# Which language in DrScheme for SICP?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket, sicp

I have been using the Module for SICP in DrScheme 4.2 but which language has the best support for SICP in DrScheme?

Has anyone here tried [this](http://planet.plt-scheme.org/display.ss?package=sicp.plt&owner=neil)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't think you need anything but [R5RS](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/) which is available in DrScheme via `Language > Choose Language...`.

You might want to allow redefinition of bindings. After you have selected R5RS, click on "`Show Details`" and uncheck "`Disallow redefinition of initial bindings`".

[Some](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-14.html#%_sec_2.1.3) [places](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-16.html#%_sec_2.3.2) [in](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-12.html#%_sec_1.3.3) the text uses an `error` function, which is not available in R5RS. In these cases you can use [srfi-23](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-23/srfi-23.html).

Another option is to simply use the "scheme" module language. Select "Module" as your language of choice and start your source files with `#lang scheme` or `#lang scheme/base`.

For the chapter "[Example: A Picture Language](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-15.html#%_sec_2.2.4)" you can try [this package](http://planet.plt-scheme.org/display.ss?package=sicp.plt&owner=soegaard) (I have not tried it myself, so I don't know how well it works).

Comment: It is now called DrRacket.

Answer (score 10):

> **SICP Support for DrRacket**
>
> This package implements support in PLT’s DrRacket for Abelson and
>   Sussman’s Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs (SICP) 2nd
>   Edition textbook, for students who wish to use DrRacket’s tools for
>   the SICP programming assignments.

http://www.neilvandyke.org/racket-sicp/

Comment: That was a part of my question: Have you used this?

Answer (score 3):

I am at the exact same place in SICP, and am using - 'Essentials of Programming Languages' as the language. It has not caused any problems yet.