# What language should DrRacket be set to when doing SICP exercises?

Tags: lisp, racket, sicp

What language should I select in DrRacket in order to do [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) exercises?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939582/which-language-in-drscheme-for-sicp , or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597781/dr-racket-problems-with-sicp

Comment: The Structure and Computer of Interpretation Programs?  :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using SICP with DrRacket, Neil Van Dyke has put together an excellent [software package](http://www.neilvandyke.org/sicp-plt/) to help with this.  Alternatively, you might be able to use the "Pretty Big" language (under Legacy languages).

The best language for using DrRacket in is the "Determine language from source" option, with `#lang racket` at the top, but SICP programs may not work perfectly in that context.

Comment: Working with SICP in school 2 years ago in DrScheme (when Racket was called PLT Scheme), we used "Pretty Big".