# C# developer starting SICP - Suggested Dev Environment?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, scheme, sicp

I've finally started reading SICP.

I downloaded [GNU/MIT Scheme](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/) it appears that I need to work in the Edwin editor which I'm sure is great when you get used to it, however I'd really prefer not to have to learn a new editor while also learning Scheme.

I was hoping there would be a Visual Studio pluggin or something similar.

I'd actual be happy just using notepad++ and just compiling using the command line.

Has anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: If you decide to use Racket, you might want to look at Neil Van Dyke's SICP support page at: http://www.neilvandyke.org/racket-sicp/ (Haven't used myself, but Eli Barzilay has recommended it a few times. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597781/dr-racket-problems-with-sicp/3598093#3598093

Comment: Try this for MIT Scheme: http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-user/Starting-Scheme-from-Microsoft-Windows.html#Starting-Scheme-from-Microsoft-Windows It looks like you might need to change the shortcut so that it doesn't start Edwin, hopefully that will get you an Emacs-free REPL.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260685/what-is-the-best-scheme-implementation-for-working-through-sicp) (a bit out of date, DrScheme is now called DrRacket).

I also see [this page](http://www.gwern.net/sicp/Introduction), which looks reasonable.

[This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939582/which-language-in-drscheme-for-sicp) asks about DrRacket directly.

Answer (score 0):

Edwin is pretty much the same as emacs, and that's worth learning.  Any text editor will do.  If you're really looking for the gui look and feel, try DrRacket?  http://www.racket-lang.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing in mit-scheme, and are familiar with Emacs there is [xscheme](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/mit-scheme/utilities.pkg/xscheme.el) for Emacs

Answer (score 0):

Neil Van Dyke also has a page where he has the book in texinfo format for emacs users.

[sicp texinfo](http://www.neilvandyke.org/sicp-texi/)

You also can find videos of lectures for the book from the 80s on youtube or going to the MIT ocw site.

[video lectures](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-001-structure-and-interpretation-of-computer-programs-spring-2005/video-lectures/)